# Point of customization - namespace injection

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, overloading

Lengthy explanation first, actual question(s) second:

In a C++ library, I want to provide points of customization. That is, certain methods can be "injected" by the user. Usually, this is done via ADL in the following way:

File `operators.h` contains:

```
namespace operators
{
    namespace print_overloads
    {
        void print_value(double x)
        {
            cout << x << endl;
        }
    }

    namespace detail
    {
        template <typename Value>
        void adl_print(Value x)
        {
            using print_overloads::print_value;
            print_value(x);
        }
    }

    template <typename Value>
    void print(Value x)
    {
        detail::adl_print(x);
    }
}
```

`print_value()` provides a point of customization via ADL. To use it, one might have in `testi.cpp`:

```
#include "operator.h"
namespace custom
{
    struct A {};

    void print_value(A)
    {
        cout << "ADL A overload" << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    operators::print(custom::A{});
}
```

This works as intended. However, it is only applicable if it is possible for the user to define a function in the corresponding namespace (`namespace custom` in this case).

My idea was to introduce a dedicated overloading namespace, `namespace print_overload`in the example above. For the user, this should allow:

```
#include "operators.h"
namespace custom_inaccessible
{
    struct A {};
}

namespace operators::print_overloads
{
    void print_value(custom_inaccessible::A)
    {
        cout << "A overload" << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    operators::print(custom_inaccessible::A{});

    int pause;
    std::cin >> pause;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The current Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 C++ compiler fails with:

`error C2664: 'void operators::print_overloads::print_value(double)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'testi::B' to 'double'`

It seems, that the overload for `print_value(A)` is not considered in the overload list. After some tinkering, I found that Conformance mode settings where set to `Yes(/permissive-)`. If I set it to `No` everything works just fine.

Now for the questions:

- Is this behavior defined in the standard?
- If so, what part of the standard is responsible for this result?
- Or is it some bug with the Visual Studio Conformance mode?

Comment: Try the code on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ for gcc and clang. But it looks like the conformance mode setting has the correct behavior and the non-conformance mode is incorrect because when resolving a function call only previously declared functions are considered, something that MSVC got wrong for templates until recently.

Comment: I would say that doing it using ADL is rather unusual. It would be better to introduce some type traits that can be specialized by user or to accept some extra template parameter with default value.

Comment: @VTT I was refering to this: http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your query about the standard, the relevant paragraphs are at [[temp.dep.candidate]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.candidate):

> For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name,
>   the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules
>   ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup, only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), only function declarations found in either
>     the template definition context or the template instantiation context
>     are found.

The above means that anything that is found on account of `using print_overloads::print_value;` (unqualified name lookup, according to the first bullet) has to already be present at the point the template is defined. A user cannot just re-open the namespace and add it afterwards.

MSVC is very correct to reject it in conformance mode.

---

To elaborate, the using declaration introduces names by qualified name lookup, according to [[namespace.udecl]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#1):

> Each using-declarator in a using-declaration introduces a set of
>   declarations into the declarative region in which the
>   using-declaration appears. The set of declarations introduced by the
>   using-declarator is found by performing qualified name lookup for the
>   name in the using-declarator, excluding functions that are hidden as
>   described below.

But, the using declaration is only introducing non-dependent names. And according to [[temp.nondep]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.nondep#1):

> Non-dependent names used in a template definition are found using the
>   usual name lookup and bound at the point they are used.

The "point they are used" being the point of the template definition.

Comment: I fail to see how `using print_overloads::print_value;` is an unqualified name lookup. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup, "For an unqualified name, that is a name that does not appear to the right of a scope resolution operator ::", this should be a qualified name lookup?

Comment: @LcdDrm - `print_value(x);` is unqualified name lookup (for `print_value`). The names made available to it by the using declaration have to be previously declared.